# Where can I find documentation on the raspberry pi 3 peripherals?

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded, armv8

I know there was an armv5 and armmv6 data sheet for this kind of thing, but there is none for the armv8, at least no publicly given. I went through: https://people-mozilla.org/~sstangl/arm/AArch64-Reference-Manual.pdf

I didn't actually read through all of it, but parsing things like: System timer, clock, peripherals, base address... is not giving me any satisfactory results.

All I want is a list of base addresses telling me what the base peripheral address is, and what the system clock's relative address is, and what the mailbox relative address is... and any and all other memory mapped peripherals.

Comment: all arm documentation is at arm infocenter.arm.com including armv8

Comment: the baremetal forum at the raspberrypi website contains a thumbnailed thread at the beginning with links to this information and more.  the peripherals are the same as the pi1 and pi2, they carved out the arm in each case, there is a little added to facilitate the new arm processors (quad core vs single) and the base address changed to permit more ram in a linear address space, other than that the actual peripheral implementation is the same just a different base address.  core processor  stuff is in the arm docs (systick, last mile of interrupt management, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ARM Architecture Reference Manual is not where the peripherals or the memory map are described.  ARM is not a chip, it is a licensed processor core IP built into chips by various licencee manufacturers who implement their own peripheral designs around it.

Broadcom provide the SoC for RPi, and it is a proprietary chip used internally by Broadcom, so that publish limited public data.  The published [Broadcom peripheral documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf) refers to the RPi1's BCM2835 but is mostly identical to the RPi2 BCM2836 and RPi3 BCM2387 with respect to the peripheral set.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation also contains a section for the RPI 3 specifically: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2837/README.md which says:

> This is the Broadcom chip used in the Raspberry Pi 3, and in later models of the Raspberry Pi 2. The underlying architecture of the BCM2837 is identical to the BCM2836.

So you can look up the docs for the Pi 2 on a sibling page https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2836/README.md which say:

> The underlying architecture in BCM2836 is identical to BCM2835.

which is at: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/README.md

So I guess you can somewhat trust in the PDFs for the Pi 1 and Pi 2 pages:

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf with errata at: https://elinux.org/BCM2835_datasheet_errata
- https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2836/QA7_rev3.4.pdf